# Error adding Foundation package using Meteorite

Tags: meteor, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to add the ZURB Foundation package (https://github.com/IslamMagdy/meteor-foundation) to a project using meteorite, but I am receiving an error.

The documentation tells me to run `mrt add foundation` in the terminal, but when I do that I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:50
  throw 'No package named ' + self.name + ' was found in the atmosphere da
                                        ^
No package named foundation was found in the atmosphere database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like atmosphere might have an issue, you could manually add the package in.

Modify you're `smart.json` file, in your apps root directory, so it looks something like (I've added the foundation package).

```
{
    "packages": {
        "foundation" :{
            "git": "https://github.com/IslamMagdy/meteor-foundation.git"
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `mrt` and it should add the package straight from git, and keep it up to date.

Edit: I tried the package above and its a bit glitchy.This did work for me however:

```
mrt add foundation-custom
```

Dont forget to remove the foundation package from your smart.json before you do this.

Comment: running mrt found the package and said it installed it successfully as it started the server, but it doesn't apply the framework's styles when I view the app in the browser.

Comment: seems the package is still a wip, updated the answer, use `foundation-custom`

Comment: I had to use "$sudo mrt"  when I used this foundation version: "git": "https://github.com/IslamMagdy/meteor-foundation.git"